# How to disable fb login based on some condition in hybridauth

Tags: php, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

How can we  disable FB login based on some condition.
For example if the time is between 2am and 4am disable the facebook login ( just an example) .
My problem is not with the logic of the condition, I can certainly apply that. but my problem is once the condition is met then how to disable the fb login programmatically  in hybridauth

Thank you in advance

Ps. you may wanna look into the code here:https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth

http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html) we can see this entry;

> **`enabled`** can be `true` or `false`; if you don't want to use a specific provider then set it to `false`

If you open [**`hybridauth/config.php`**](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/hybridauth/config.php), you'll see a configuration array, which holds configurations for different authentication methods. Most interestingly, we can see an key named `enabled`, which we can manipulate.

#### Modifying the value directly.

We can modify the value directly, by using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). For example;

```
...

"Facebook" => array ( 
                "enabled" => (condition ? true : false), //Ternary operator modifying `enabled` value.
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" ),
                "trustForwarded" => false
            ),
....
```

However, we can do this by modifying it after the configuration has been loaded.

#### Modifying the value later on.

If you open up [**`examples/social_hub/login.php`**](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/dbed9a8f4b9cc1c1ea26cb689dafc4e58db0ca3c/examples/social_hub/login.php), you'll see we load the config file and use it. Here is where we can modify that `enabled` key.

The configuration is held within the variable `$config`, so;

```
if( condition ) {
  $config['providers']['Facebook']['enabled'] = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your super simplified example you could just add logic to build a configuration array on the fly as appropriate and then inject that into your hybridauth instance. This could be achieved by loading in the standard config array and then manipulating according to whatever business logic rules you have.

You could always extend Hybridauth but that seems overkill for the relatively simple example that you have provided.